# how to solve error to play any audio/video file through media player?

Tags: android

here is my IO Exception error logcat....

```
03-25 09:41:17.950: D/dalvikvm(10906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 7% free 2629K/2800K, paused 54ms, total 60ms
03-25 09:41:17.962: I/dalvikvm-heap(10906): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.167MB for 512016-byte allocation
03-25 09:41:18.030: D/dalvikvm(10906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3126K/3304K, paused 64ms, total 64ms
03-25 09:41:18.149: D/dalvikvm(10906): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 3126K/3304K, paused 12ms+8ms, total 119ms
03-25 09:41:18.289: D/dalvikvm(10906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 3126K/3304K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
03-25 09:41:18.349: I/dalvikvm-heap(10906): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.637MB for 3640620-byte allocation
03-25 09:41:18.439: D/dalvikvm(10906): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 6681K/6860K, paused 30ms+5ms, total 99ms
03-25 09:41:19.089: D/gralloc_goldfish(10906): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-25 09:41:24.129: D/dalvikvm(10906): GC_CONCURRENT freed 515K, 8% free 7537K/8172K, paused 6ms+7ms, total 301ms
03-25 09:41:28.030: D/++++++++++++length++++++++++(10906): 3
03-25 09:41:28.479: I/Choreographer(10906): Skipped 570 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 09:41:29.730: I/Choreographer(10906): Skipped 96 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 09:41:32.980: E/MediaPlayer(10906): error (1, -2147483648)
03-25 09:41:33.000: W/System.err(10906): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
03-25 09:41:33.011: W/System.err(10906):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
03-25 09:41:33.020: W/System.err(10906):    at com.example.assetsfolderaccess.PlayFromAssetsActivity$1.onItemClick(PlayFromAssetsActivity.java:80)
03-25 09:41:33.030: W/System.err(10906):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
03-25 09:41:33.030: W/System.err(10906):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
03-25 09:41:33.039: W/System.err(10906):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
03-25 09:41:33.049: W/System.err(10906):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
03-25 09:41:33.049: W/System.err(10906):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-25 09:41:33.059: W/System.err(10906):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-25 09:41:33.069: W/System.err(10906):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 09:41:33.069: W/System.err(10906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-25 09:41:33.079: W/System.err(10906):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 09:41:33.089: W/System.err(10906):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 09:41:33.089: W/System.err(10906):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-25 09:41:33.099: W/System.err(10906):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-25 09:41:33.109: W/System.err(10906):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 09:44:43.119: D/dalvikvm(11364): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 46K, 7% free 2629K/2804K, paused 284ms, total 288ms
03-25 09:44:43.129: I/dalvikvm-heap(11364): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.167MB for 512016-byte allocation
03-25 09:44:43.349: D/dalvikvm(11364): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3126K/3308K, paused 218ms, total 218ms
03-25 09:44:43.519: D/dalvikvm(11364): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 3126K/3308K, paused 32ms+18ms, total 170ms
03-25 09:44:43.749: D/dalvikvm(11364): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 3126K/3308K, paused 70ms, total 70ms
03-25 09:44:43.829: I/dalvikvm-heap(11364): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.637MB for 3640620-byte allocation
03-25 09:44:44.049: D/dalvikvm(11364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 6681K/6864K, paused 91ms+9ms, total 224ms
03-25 09:44:44.689: D/gralloc_goldfish(11364): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-25 09:47:09.600: D/dalvikvm(11364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 515K, 8% free 7534K/8172K, paused 78ms+142ms, total 459ms
03-25 09:47:14.040: D/++++++++++++length++++++++++(11364): 3
03-25 09:47:14.080: I/Choreographer(11364): Skipped 598 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 09:47:15.039: I/Choreographer(11364): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 09:47:20.260: D/-----path----(11364): arti.mp3
03-25 09:47:20.299: E/MediaPlayer(11364): error (1, -2147483648)
03-25 09:47:20.319: W/System.err(11364): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
03-25 09:47:20.330: W/System.err(11364):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
03-25 09:47:20.330: W/System.err(11364):    at com.example.assetsfolderaccess.PlayFromAssetsActivity$1.onItemClick(PlayFromAssetsActivity.java:82)
03-25 09:47:20.339: W/System.err(11364):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
03-25 09:47:20.339: W/System.err(11364):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
03-25 09:47:20.350: W/System.err(11364):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
03-25 09:47:20.350: W/System.err(11364):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
03-25 09:47:20.350: W/System.err(11364):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-25 09:47:20.371: W/System.err(11364):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-25 09:47:20.371: W/System.err(11364):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 09:47:20.379: W/System.err(11364):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-25 09:47:20.390: W/System.err(11364):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 09:47:20.390: W/System.err(11364):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 09:47:20.399: W/System.err(11364):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-25 09:47:20.399: W/System.err(11364):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-25 09:47:20.399: W/System.err(11364):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is my Code.....

```
itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View v, int pos, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String path =  parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), path,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Log.d("-----path----","" +path);
        mp=new MediaPlayer();
        try {

            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(path);
            /*mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });*/
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shows:

```
 The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

This error occurs when user performs heavy operations in main thread, remember Android is single threaded system, there is Single main thread where all the other subsystem hooks upon to perform task such as Activities,Services,Content Providers. That's why when you perform network operation directly on main thread you get such message.

Answer (score 0):

Rstart your AVD and you can try this

```
itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View v, int pos, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String path =  parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), path,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //  Log.d("-----path----","" +path);
        mp=new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;
            descriptor = yourclassName.this.getAssets().openFd(test.mp3);   
            mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),descriptor.getStartOffset(),descriptor.getLength() );  
            descriptor.close();
            mp.prepare();   
            mp.start

        }  catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```